# Drupal Commerce: Can I split payment over multiple credit cards?

Tags: 7, commerce

I need to enable my customers to be able to split payments over multiple credit cards.  Is it possible with Commerce, and where can I find documentation to that end?

Comment: Is it even legal by the agreements you have with credit card center (or whatever they are called)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

It is not possible now. [It was requested](https://www.drupal.org/node/1096504), and it is **Closed (won't fix)** - if you want it, you need to code it yourself.

> This isn't something Commerce can do out of the box, and I'm not entirely sure it would fit in. However, in a contributed module, you should be able to look at the order balance before moving forward to the checkout completion page and requesting additional payment from the customer if necessary. For now, I'm just going to have to mark this "won't fix" as no easy ideas come to mind for how we could make this abstract enough to solve in core. The main problem in core would be how you visualize the outstanding balance and accommodate both on-site and off-site payment methods.

Comment: there is a sandbox module in that thread that could be a starting point for anyone to finish the add-on functionality ...

Comment: @tenken is there enough code to bother?

Comment: looks like a hefty (re)starting point for any beginner developer to me http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-zulfierken-1502028/tree/ (D7 port)

Comment: This is sorta what I saw... various other plugins HALF solve this... Point of Sale can manage split payments to some degree... most store credit/gift card plugins have to have a split payment option for them to work...
We are likely going to end up going with the "Amazon Solution"... buy "credits" or a "gift card" with Card A, and then use that to purchase the item, paying the remaining difference with Card B

Comment: @OhkaBaka remember most of these modules are GPL, so you can use and adjust their code to your needs.